# Databricks: Dataframe spliting using explode

Tags: python, databricks

Suppose I am having the following spark data frame 
[image]

And I would like to transform to the following dataframe . Need to use explode function ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can use arrays_zip to get the pairs and then use explode function .

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, explode, arrays_zip}
dfx.withColumn("zipped", arrays_zip(col("MemberProperty"), col("Value")))
  .withColumn("exploded", explode(col("zipped")))
  .drop("MemberProperty", "Value")
  .withColumn("MemberProperty", col("exploded.MemberProperty"))
  .withColumn("Value", col("exploded.Value"))
```

Comment: from what I have tested with your code . the rows are duplicating. strange

Comment: Memberproperty x Value

Comment: oh sorry I thought you wanted to cross multiply. I'll update the code